# Graphical view of tables in SQL Server CE

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0, sql-server-ce

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 with a SQL Server CE database.

The queries work just fine, the only problem is I didn't find any way to view the actual content of the tables... Meaning - I would want to install the database on workspace such Navicat to view the tables, but I couldn't find one to fit SQL Server CE.

Is there any?

Answer (score 0):

You can view the table content from Server Explorer, or you can install an app like sql compact Toolbox to view/edit table content. What is Navicat?